# How to send multiple text field values to next pho page when the text field is created using while loop?

Tags: php, html

How do I pass multiple text field values of a form which were created using a while loop to another page?

```
echo”<form method=\”POST\” action =\”store.php\”>”;
While($result = mysqli_fetch_row($exec))
{
echo $result[0].” “ .$result[1].” “;
echo “<input text =\”type\” name=\” marks\”>”;
}
echo “<input type=\”submit\”>”;
echo “</form>”;
```

The above code works fine but when the loop creates multiple text fields and when I submit the form only latest is sent to store.php.
My question is how to send all values.?

Comment: You want to use an "array notation": `echo '<input text ="type" name="marks[]">';` That will create a entry in the `$_POST` superglobal variable named "marks" which is an array.

Comment: And apart from that you really want to watch your quotes: `“` and `"` are separate characters. You appear to confuse them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array notation. Which contain all value as an array

Comment: A good quality answer would also give a specific example of what you mean by this...